# bash printf giving me Invalid String operator

Tags: string, bash, printf, operator-keyword

I've got a script that calculates the numerical value of the previous month by assigning a variable to the current month, checks if that value is '01', and if so, assign a `previous_month` variable to '12', or subtract 1 from the value and assign that new value to the `previous_month`

Here is a snippet of the code in question: a variable declaration and an `if` statement

```
# Set current month
current_month=`date +"%m"`

# Check if current month = Jan
if [ $current_month -eq "01" ]
    then
        previous_month=12
    else
        previous_month=$(printf %02d $(expr $current_month - 1))
fi
```

Here is the output from running /bin/sh -x myScript.sh

```
+ [ 09 -eq 01 ]
+ expr 09 - 1
+ printf %02d Invalid string operator
+ previous_month=00
```

Whats really bugging me is that this a) used to work, and b) works if I write the code in a shell (copy / paste)

I can't find a way to get this to work and I need to have the `previous_month` variable two characters with a leading zero if the month is < 10

Comment: Work on Ubuntu 16.04 (previous_month=08 at the end)

Comment: The "Invalid string operator" isn't coming from `printf`, it's coming from `expr` (and being passed to `printf` as arguments). You might be running into trouble with numbers with leading "0" being treated as octal, and hence "08" and "09" not being valid numbers. BTW, when you start the script with `/bin/sh`, you're overriding its shebang line and using the `sh` shell (which might or might not actually be bash).

Comment: Note that you can replace `$(expr $current_month - 1)` with `$(( $current_month - 1))`. Aside from regular expression matching, there is very little need for `expr` in a modern POSIX environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the Number being interpreted as OCTAL by `printf`. Since i am not able to reproduce the issue.Can you check if this work around helps.

```
previous_month=$(printf "%0*d\n" 2 $(expr $current_month - 1))
```

or

```
value=$(expr $current_month - 1)
previous_month=$(printf %02d "${value#0}")
```

Comment: Neither of these work, unfortunately. the first gives me `invalid format string` and if I do the second and `echo $value`, I get `Invalid string operator`

Answer (score 1):

@skr didn't have the answer 100%, but they gave me something to work with and test.

I had to use the curly braces around the `current_month` variable and add `#0`, not sure what this does, exactly, but I'm assuming its allowing `printf` to see that value as an integer instead of a string.

The variable `previous_month` needed to be assigned as follows:

```
previous_month=$(printf %02d $(expr ${current_month#0} - 1))
```

And this is the output of running `/bin/sh -x myScript.sh`

```
+ [ 09 -eq 01 ]
+ expr 9 - 1
+ printf %02d 8
+ previous_month=08
```